# JSON2CSV not outputting values

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a document that resembles:

```
[
  {
    "subscriberid": "4355",
    "Title": "Miss",
    "FirstName": "FirstName",
    "LastName": "LastName",
    "EmailAddress": "thisisanemail@email.com",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Postcode": "B1 3qq",
    "Gender": "",
    "SubscribeDate": "2015-08-12 10:58:29",
    "Birthday": "31-5-1985",
    "Kids": "no",
    "Kidsages": "",
    "Student": "no",
    "Favourite": "1113111",
    "attendreason": "Array",
    "MarketingOptIn": "Y",
    "Source": "WEBSITE",
    "Login": [
      {
        "subscriberid": "4355",
        "Created_at": "2017-05-18 10:09:44",
        "IPaddress": "1.1.2.3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "subscriberid": "125",
    "Title": "",
    "FirstName": "FirstName2",
    "LastName": "LastName2",
    "EmailAddress": "thisisalsoanemail@email.com",
    "Mobile": "",
    "Postcode": "tn39 4de",
    "Gender": "",
    "SubscribeDate": "2015-12-02 17:21:18",
    "Birthday": "13-3-1922",
    "Kids": "no",
    "Kidsages": "",
    "Student": "no",
    "Favourite": "8108200",
    "attendreason": "Date",
    "MarketingOptIn": "Y",
    "Source": "FACEBOOK",
    "Vouchers": [
      {
        "subscriberid": "213",
        "Created_at": "2017-05-18 08:57:47",
        "Source": "some website",
        "offer": "50offMains",
        "name": "50% off Mains"
      }
    ],
    "Login": [
      {
        "subscriberid": "123",
        "Created_at": "2017-05-18 07:57:46",
        "IPaddress": "1.2.3.4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I'm trying to turn it into a CSV, automatically. Normally this would be a very simple script with json2csv, but for some reason this time I'm having an issue that I'm struggling to troubleshoot. My file is being created, but with headers only and no data.

I read the docs on `https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv` and I'm thinking I would use dot notation for the fields but due to how it's setup, I'm unsure what would preceed the dot?

I tried CLI version and an actual JS Version but same deal. All I get is the headers. As you'll see in the script, I only care about parts of the JSON Document, but even if I try to do it all, I still only get the headers. My previous versions have all used glob, but the CLI and pointing directly to the file still nets the same result.

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var glob = require('glob');

let fields = 
    [
        "subscriberid",
        "Title",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "EmailAddress",
        "Mobile",
        "Postcode",
        "Gender",
        "SubscribeDate",
        "Birthday",
        "Kids",
        "Kidsages",
        "Student",
        "Favourite",
        "attendreason",
        "MarketingOptIn",
        "Source"
    ];

let dataInput = glob("path/**/toFile.txt");

var csv = json2csv({ data: dataInput, fields: fields });

fs.writeFile('output.csv', csv, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('file saved');
});
```

Comment: You wrote: "My file is being created, but with headers and only data." What output were you expecting?

Comment: @BPS Thanks for catching that. It's only outputting the headers, and no data. Corrected the wording.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with you. Have you solved this issue? thx.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I am facing the same issue